# jquery colorbox and jquery date picker

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using jquery colorbox and jquery date picker. My problem is date picker doesn't work in my popup window using jquery colorbox. I tried to used outside colorbox and its work fine.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

I tried the code below but still doesn't work.

```
    onLoad: function(){
        $('#date-pick').datepick();         
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may write these codes `$('#date-pick').datepick();`  in colorbox's `onComplete` function. When all dom elements are ready then the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, to create the datepicker with jquery-ui its:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

It may well be something else, but you really haven't shown us much. I don't even know if you're using the jquery-ui datepicker as you've provided very little information in your question.